# Import third party library not available on npm in Ionic 2 rc

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have an external JS file containing some methods and third party library integration. Now, I want to include this JS file as a module in my Ionic 2 rc build project. The steps that I followed are as follows:

- `declare module 'Appgeneral';` in the file `src/declarations.d.ts`
- Including a `<script>` tag in the `index.html` since it is a JS file
- Creating an object in `home.ts` :  `var appgeneral = new Appgeneral();`
- Appgeneral.js contains the following code:

  ```
  function Appgeneral(){}
  Appgeneral.prototype.methodCall = function() {
          console.log("Done!");
          return true;
  };
  ```

The methods should be accessible in `home.ts` using the newly created object `appgeneral`. It was working fine in the beta.11 version. However, after upgrading to the rc build, I'm getting an error stating cannot resolve the module `Appgeneral`.

Also, I converted my `Appgeneral.js` to `Appgeneral.ts` exporting the entire class as follows:

```
module Appgeneral{
   export class Appgeneral{
     public methodCall() {
        console.log("Done!");
        return true;
     }
   }
}
```

Then, I tried to import it in the `home.ts` as follows: `import { Appgeneral } from './src/ts/Appgeneral'`.  Still, the error persists.

> Cannot find name 'Appgeneral'. 
>         L14:  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
>         L15:    public appgeneral: Appgeneral) {

The documentation provided at [Third Party libs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/) is applicable to external libraries which are available on `npm`. However, I want to include my third party library directly within the app.

This is my  `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.8.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

These are my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.0.3",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ionic-native": "^2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  }
```